# i want to join two datasets with rdd in spark scala and save results to file. It was executing in all nodes but the last task running forever

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my code::

```
val trg = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(Map("path"-> {path+"/test/phonesort.csv"}, "header" -> "true")).load().toDF().repartition(1000) //10 million data

val src = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(Map("path"-> {path+"/test/bajaj_src.csv"}, "header" -> "true")).load().toDF().sort("PHONE1").repartition(10) //1,00,000 data

val srcrdd = src.rdd.map(row => { (row(1),row)}).persist()
val brd = sc.broadcast(srcrdd) //BROADCASTING SAMLL DATASET
 val trgrdd = trg.rdd.map ( row => {
   (row(1),row)
})
val res = trgrdd.join(brd.value) map{ case (x,(y,z)) => y.mkString("\"","\",\"","\"")+","+z.mkString("\"","\",\"" , "\"") }
 res.saveAsTextFile(path+"/test/1.csv")
```

The problem is when i am trying to execute in 3 node cluster the last task going into infinite loop (forever not completing the task).
here i am sharing screenshots of my job running status with marked::
Request someone's help here.. Thanks

[image: screenshot of jobs]

[image: screenshot of details of stage]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your keys aren't well distributed.

Join calls a cogroup which puts all the data with the same key into the same partition/task.

In this case u have 44259072 records with the same key so they are all being processed by a single CPU in a single thread.

Look at your data to find this value and decide whether you actually want to join on it. I expect you don't since every case I've seen this its actually a dummy value.
If you do then I'm not sure how to proceed. You'd get even more records out since joining several values on the same key effectively does a cartesian join.

EDIT: 
Reading your code further if I understand you are broadcasting an RDD?
You shouldn't do this. You should do something like the following:

```
val smallRDD: RDD[(K, V)] = ???
val largeRDD: RDD[(K, V)] = ???
val bcRDD: Broadcast[Map[K, V]] = sc.broadcast(smallRDD.collectAsMap())
val joined = largeRDD.map{case (k, v) => (k, (v, bcRDD(k)) }
```

If the above doesn't apply and I'm reading your code wrong it is possible you data is evenly distributed but they end up on the same partiton. This could happen when the hashcode of the keys modded by the number of partitions equals the same value. In which case you will want to look into writing your own partitioner.

Comment: thanks, so how to process with this kind of data available and here the large file has sorted data with the key what i want to join

Comment: New to stack-overflow so not sure if you get a notification when I edit my answer so posting a comment just to be sure.